# How do I interpret dates like 1394862706?

Tags: date, datetime, decode, date-format

I don't know how to interpret this date format:

`1394862706`,
`1394862645`,
`1400258321`,
`1400258250` etc. (each block is a different date)

Does someone understand in which format are them?

Comment: http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they're [Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). For example, `1400258250` [maps to](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1400258250+unix+time&x=-989&y=-72) `4:37:30 May 16 2014`. They represent the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch, January 1, 1970.

Here's a nice [timestamp converter](http://www.epochconverter.com).

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the 10-digit numbers are Unix timestamps, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00, the Unix Epoch.

If you have GNU `date`, you can use the `-d` option (or `--date`) and the `@` prefix to analyze them (here, with `TZ=US/Pacific` or `TZ=America/Los_Angeles`):

```
$ for ts in 1394862706 1394862645 1400258321 1400258250; do date -d @$ts; done
Fri Mar 14 22:51:46 PDT 2014
Fri Mar 14 22:50:45 PDT 2014
Fri May 16 09:38:41 PDT 2014
Fri May 16 09:37:30 PDT 2014
$
```

If you add the `-u` or `--utc` option, then you get the output:

```
Sat Mar 15 05:51:46 UTC 2014
Sat Mar 15 05:50:45 UTC 2014
Fri May 16 16:38:41 UTC 2014
Fri May 16 16:37:30 UTC 2014
```